# GNU screen keeps changing window title on start & exit of vim

Tags: vim, gnu-screen, xterm

My status line in screen is:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline "%{= Wk}%-Lw%50>%{= BW}%n%f* %t%{= Wk}%+Lw%<"
```

This always shows a list of windows with their names. I have also bound C-a T to set this back, in case there is some binary output to stdout and it changes.

However, since the last update to some package, it keeps changing whenever I open vim to

```
[No Name] - VIM
```

Then, whenever I close vim, I get

```
 - Terminal - Terminal - Terminal - Terminal
```

It starts with just one " - Terminal", but each time, there is one more. Screen also propagates this to the xterm window title of the terminal emulator.

So, whenever I open or close vim (and probably some other programs as well), I have to press C-a T. This is getting annoying.

How can I turn this off?

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Screen version 4.06.02 (GNU) 23-Oct-17
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun 07 2019 11:40:34)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that what I actually wanted was a caption, not a hardstatus:

> **`caption`** [ **`top`** | **`bottom`** ] **`always`**|**`splitonly`** [*`string`*]
>
> **`caption string`** [*`string`*]
>
> This command controls the display of the window  captions.  Normally a
> caption  is  only  used if more than one window is shown on the display
> (split screen mode).  But if the type is set to `always`, screen shows a
> caption even if only one window is displayed. 
> The default is `splitonly`.
>
> The  second form changes the text used for the caption.  You can use all
> escapes from the "[STRING ESCAPES](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/screen.1.html#STRING_ESCAPES)" chapter. 
> Screen uses a default of ‘`%3n %t`’.
>
> You can mix both forms by providing a string as an additional argument.
>
> You  can  have the caption displayed either at the top or bottom of the
> window.  The default is bottom.

– Source: [(screen(1) man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/screen.1.html). 
See also: [(GNU) Screen User’s Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Caption.html).

So, I set `hardstatus` to `alwaysignore` and added:

```
caption bottom always
caption always "%{= Wk}%-Lw%50>%{= BW}%n%f* %t%{= Wk}%+Lw%<"
```

The problem with "- Terminal" appearing multiple times in the status
was caused by the terminal emulator (`xfce4-terminal`).